# Is there any application for viewing medical images (3D) with .scn format?

Tags: image, image-processing, scenekit, medical

I have images that are in .scn format and I would like to view them. I generally use tools like ITK SNAP and slicer 3D.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not related to SceneKit. Several tools use the `scn` file extension (for instance the Godot engine also uses it for 3D scenes).

I dont know anything about medical software, but a web search seems to indicate that *Image Lab* from Bio-Rad uses the `.scn` file extension for images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SOFA](https://www.sofa-framework.org/) framework to view medical 3D images in .scn format